# client side pre-commit hooks in subversion

Tags: svn, hook, svn-hooks, pre-commit

Is any way to setup pre-commit hooks on the client side with an svn client, for example through eclipse or a command line svn client ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But you can alias your own script to svn, so it gets called every time you type `svn`. The script then calls actual svn. How about that?

Comment: ofcourse- doh moment. I should have specified only eclipse because I want to use it from inside eclipse -subclipse plugin

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it's any help in your particular case, but [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (on Windows) supports client-side hooks.