# SVN - Get commit size in start-commit hook?

Tags: svn, commit, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Actually, I check the size of a commit in the pre-commit hook. But all the files are commited before I can refuse the commit in pre-commit.

For example, if the size limit is 10 MB and the user sends 1 GB file, the 1 GB will be completely transfered to my server and then the pre-commit hook will refuse the transaction.

I want to refuse the transaction if the commit size is greater that the repository limit before all the files are transfered to the server.

How is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798201/client-side-pre-commit-hooks-in-subversion ?

Answer (score 0):

TSVN Supports client side hooks, the release notes are [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.5_releasenotes.html#client-side-hooks), and the documentation is [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Comment: I don't have access to add client-side hooks.

Answer (score -1):

See the apache directives LimitRequestBody and LimitXMLRequestBody

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitxmlrequestbody