# In Eclipse How Can I Edit With One Format And Commit With Another

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, formatting, pre-commit

Everyone on my team uses the same formater settings so files in the SVN repo dont have changes based on formatting. The format that was chosen I dislike and I can barely read.

Is there a plugin for Eclipse or a setting in Eclipse that will auto reformat a file to my own style while editing, and then reformat the file to my team settings before a commit?

I have seen tips to apply your current formatting before a commit, but I want it to apply some other format before a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4798201/85950) about setting up client-side pre-commit hooks for Subversion.  Not a plugin, but maybe sufficient.

You could likely also set up something similar to automatically format code the way you want it on checkout so that you could remain largely ignorant of the in-repo formatting.

Any solution along the lines you request is almost certainly going to break features of Subversion like `diff`, though.  The first-best solution is probably to find a format that everyone on the team agrees on, if that's possible.

Comment: I like the idea of hijacking the svn commands to change the format of my files, Thanks for that link. Now I need to find a command line way to apply the formatting.